# Bootstrap navbar-default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I was looking at the examples that bootstrap gives on their site for their navbar-default (getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default), I ran across some html which I did not understand:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

An explanation of the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what didnt you understand about this???

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

1) The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application, it's signaling to collapse the navbar at defined breakpoints in screen width within bootstrap (responsiveness).

2)The data target is the bootstrap navbar in the example, see 1).

3) `data-toggle="collapse"` signals the bootstrap API to collapse the navbar.

4) You can read more about aria here [ARIA Mozilla Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)

Answer (score 0):

When the browser get stretched over a breakpoint that is smaller then the viewport your links will collapse to a toggle button that html is used to specify how the toggle will look and what ul is used for the collapses menu